# ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object with function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I'm trying to write a function can return conut of number of traverlers by number of flight in Oracle 'SQL'
my Code is

```
Create or replace function TravelersCount(flightNumber in number)
Return number
Is
Travelers_Count number(20); 
BEGIN

Select count(traveler_number) into Travelers_Count from Travel_details where flight_number = flightNumber;
return Travelers_Count;
END;
```

but I got an this error message

```
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Please help me in this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the function name `TravelersCount` to different value. Looks there is some other object with this name

`Create or replace function` **TravelersCount** `(flightNumber in number)`
...

Comment: Thank u so much.. I did not notice that

Answer (score 0):

Check it with

```
select * from user_objects where object_name = 'TRAVELERSCOUNT';
```

See object's type and decide what to do (whether to drop it and reuse that object name, or change function's name to something else).

---

A suggestion, if I may: you named parameter almost the same as column name:

```
where flight_number = flightNumber
```

It makes it difficult to distinguish which is which. Usually, we precede parameters with some prefix, e.g. `p_` or `par_`. Also, it is a good habit to always use table aliases, to avoid confusion. Finally, in Oracle all object names default to UPPERCASE (we don't use `MixedCase`, but underscores as in `mixed_case`) but you can reference them using any case you want.

So:

```
create or replace function f_travelers_count (p_flight_number in number)
  return number
is
  travelers_count number(20); 
begin
  select count(t.traveler_number) 
    into travelers_count 
    from travel_details t
    where t.flight_number = p_flight_number;

  return travelers_count;
end;
```